# PHP redirect header is not redirecting?

Tags: javascript, php, redirect, authentication, header

I am using following code to redirect

```
header('Location: '.$fileID.'php');
}
else if (!isset($_SESSION['login']))
echo '<p>you need to register first.</p>' ;
?>
```

$fileID has a value bacuse I am using this value in other part of code and that works fine. I also tried

```
echo '<script>window.location="'.$fileID.'php"</script>';
```

but got a notfound error. I would like to get it working by any of these methods but would prefer the header method. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What do you see if you use `echo` instead of `header`? Is the right value showing up? Have you got error reporting turned on?

Comment: If you are getting a "not found" error then that means the redirect is working, you've just got the path to the file wrong. Try specifying the full url to the file and see if that works

Comment: Do you mean when I use the echo with script code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted to put this in a comment but I don't have enough reputation :( Anyways try changing your header from this:

```
header('Location: '.$fileID.'php');
```

To this:

```
header('Location: '.$fileID.'.php');
```

Comment: With header it is still not working. However, it started working with the echo script code. Am I missing something else here?

Comment: That's it. Glad you fixed it :)

Comment: So, I should not worry about the header? It would bug me why it is not working.

Comment: Nope, that should be fine ;)

Answer (score 1):

1. You should `exit;` after redirect with headers, because the script will go on executing otherwise which can lead to unintended side effects.
2. > but got a notfound error.

URL seems wrong, echo the output and see if it matches your expected location.

Comment: +1 for `exit;` - and I think he's probably missing the `.` in `.php` extension: `echo '<script>window.location="'.$fileID.'.php"</script>';`

Comment: @SetSailMedia It has started working with the script code. Is there something I can do about the headers?